# Метрики кода VS

Tags: c++, visual-studio

В `Visual Studio 2015` хочу рассчитать метрики кода, а появляется ошибка

> В целевом файле проекта нет управляемого кода

Что делать?

Comment: Ничего не делать, метрики считаются только для managed кода. Можно пользоватся сторонними тулзами, например: http://www.campwoodsw.com/sourcemonitor.html

Comment: @PetrAbdulin, оформите в виде ответа, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Ничего не делать, метрики считаются только для managed кода.
Можно пользоватся сторонними утилитами, например [SourceMonitor](http://www.campwoodsw.com/sourcemonitor.html).